# Reading from API And compare Date to display something

Tags: javascript, angular

So, the this is about consuming an API that has a date/time property. The content should change every 3 hours by comparing current user Date/time with that of the API and also assigning past and upcoming hours in a separate an arrays to be displayed in other section of the page. I managed to assign past and upcoming dates to their respective arrays. I need to compare the date and to assign "current data" if the user Date/Time is equal to or within 3 hours in a property to display it for the whole duration of three hours.

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data:any[])=>{
const now = new Date('2021-02-14 09:00:00');

 for (const item of data) {
   const apiDate = new Date(item.dateTime);

    if(now.getTime() > apiDate.getTime()){
     this.future.push('future dates')
   } else if(now.getTime() < apiDate.getTime()){
     this.past.push('past dates')
   }else if(now.getTime() == apiDate.getTime()){
    //in real time, they'll only be equal for one second
    this.current = 'Show NOW'
   }
 }
```

This is the structure of API/Json Data retuned

```
[ {  "number": 10,   "dateTime": "2021-02-14 00:00:00" }, {  "number": 20,   "dateTime": "2021-02-14 03:00:00" }, {  "number": 30,   "dateTime": "2021-02-14 06:00:00" }, {  "number": 40,   "dateTime": "2021-02-14 09:00:00" }, {  "number": 50,   "dateTime": "2021-02-14 12:00:00" }]
```

a better approach to this would even be better.

Thanks

Comment: sorry, but your question is to improve the existing code?:)

Comment: No my question is how to display the "message" for 3 full hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your want to show time within range, then you can create an object with your time boundaries:

```
getTimeInterval = () => {
    const from = new Date();
    const to = new Date(from);
    to.setHours(to.getHours() + 3)
    return { from, to };
}
```

and then just check both boundaries of date `from` and `to`:

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data:any[])=>{

    const dateRange = this.getTimeInterval();
    
    for (const item of data) {
       const apiDate = new Date(item.dateTime);
    
        if (dateRange.from.getTime() > apiDate.getTime()
           && dateRange.to.getTime() > apiDate.getTime())
        {
            this.future.push('future dates');
        } 
        else if(dateRange.from.getTime() < apiDate.getTime())
        {
            this.past.push('past dates')
        } 
        else if (dateRange.from.getTime() >= apiDate.getTime()
            && dateRange.to.getTime() <= apiDate.getTime())
        {                 
            this.current = 'Show NOW'
        }
 }
```